# mysql syntax error with a query that works directly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute a query in rails with:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query.join)
```

I build the query as a string and it looks like this:

```
UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 2728740 WHERE id = 2728797;
 UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 2728725 WHERE id = 2728767;
 UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 2728735 WHERE id = 2728783;
 UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 2728727 WHERE id = 2728770;
 UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 2728751 WHERE id = 2728838;
```

When executing the query from rails i get an error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE balance_lines
>   SET parent_id = 2728725 WHERE id = 2728767;

But when I execute it from the mysql UI - it works! what is the problem?

Comment: You are trying to run more than one query at once. You probably can't do that. You need to run them one at a time.

Comment: i don't know what the problem is but you can probably loop through query and execute each one.

Comment: @JohnConde - But I want to save time and make one query for all. How can I achieve that? This is only the beginning of the string. It has 50-100 lines like these!

Comment: This could work `query.each{ |q| ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(q) }`, maybe wrapped in a DB Transaction

Comment: @MrYoshiji - But what if I want to make only one roundtrip to the server in order to make the app faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that with CASE statment:

```
  UPDATE balance_lines SET parent_id = 
         CASE WHEN id = 2728797  THEN 2728740
              WHEN id = 2728767  THEN 2728725
              WHEN id = 2728783  THEN 2728735
              WHEN id = 2728770  THEN 2728727
              WHEN id = 2728838  THEN 2728751

         END
  WHERE id  in (2728797,2728767,2728783,2728770,2728838)
```